# Can't generate image using PHP

Tags: php

Why the following code doesn't show image in browser, anyone sees any errors?

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 191, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$generator = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789',5)),0,8);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5, $generator, $text_color);
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: Are any errors generated?  Do the requests indicate success (http 200)?

Comment: Begin removing `@` from your code. And remove whitespaces before `<?php`

Comment: No errors, removing @ didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a(or multiple) space(s) before the `<?php` that will cause a failure. Your script works unless you have that space.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
//....etc.
?>
```

**Not:**

```
    <?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
//....etc.
?>
```